# change data type between 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c++

I need to change the datatype between different OS version in C++.
is it possible to define a macro into H file. will it be good practice.

Ex

```
if os_version=32
             long =long
    if os_version=64
              long =int
```

Is there any macro/variable which help me to determine that it is 64 bit machine or 32 bit machine

Comment: You are going down a dark path my friend. Take a look at stdint.h for the 'best' way to do this.

Comment: But purpose was to maintain some backward comparability in case some issue happen

Comment: Don't even think about changing the meaning of `long`. That's crazy talk.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan now `#define true (rand()%2)`. That has some teeth =P

Answer (score 4):

You could use exact-width integer types instead (declared in `<cstdint>`)

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
```

This way the sizes are fixed on all the platforms that provide them.

Comment: its `stdint.h` and `cstdint` respectively for C and C++, though some implementations don't have the latter yet. (oh, and +1)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the stdint.h library.

As a matter of fact you are no more using 'int' type but uint32_t for a 32 bits unsigned integer, or uint64_t for a 64 bits unsigned integer.

This library gives you other types. So, by using it, you will not have to be worried about the targeted platform (32/64 bits).

The con is that you will have to change all the types used already into your code, but you will have a code definitely much more portable.